# Ionic 3 Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

i need help with this strangeness that i cant figure out, i keep getting Property 'password' does not exist on type 'User'. even though, i declared password as a string on my user.ts class

user.ts

```
    export interface User{
    email: string;

    password: string;
}
```

my register page

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.email"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

      <ion-item>
      <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block (click)="register(user)">Cadastrar</button>
```

my register.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cadastro',
  templateUrl: 'cadastro.html',
})
export class CadastroPage {

  user = {} as User;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth

  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CadastroPage');
  }
  async register(user: User){
    try{
    const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password);
    console.log(result);
    }
    catch(e){
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You haven't imported user.ts in register.ts.

Comment: `User` is coming from `firebase/app`. Are you sure that `User` has the properties you want?

Comment: true lol, auto import was importing it from firebase/app, instead of my local files, thanks for the quick answer!